# Not sure how to avoid duplicating code here

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this bit of code, which works great and does exactly what I want it to do:

```
            if condition1 {
                array1 += [array1[i-n]]
            } else {
                array1 += [Int (arc4random_uniform(7))]
                if array1[i] >= array1[i-n] {
                    array1[i] += 1
                }
            } //same logic, different condition and array
            if condition2 {
                array2 += [array2[i-n]]
            } else {
                array2 += [Int (arc4random_uniform(7))]
                if array2[i] >= array2[i-n] {
                    array2[i] += 1
                }
            }
```

But I'm doing the exact same thing twice, just with a different condition and different array.  How can I avoid duplicating the logic?  I tried packaging it up as an array of two tuples:

```
[ (condition1, array1) , (condition2, array2) ]
```

and I put that in a for loop:

```
for tuple in [ (condition1, array1) , (condition2, array2) ] {
    var (condition, array) = tuple
    if condition {
        array += [array[i-n]]
    } else {
        array += [Int (arc4random_uniform(7))]
        if array[i] >= array[i-n] {
            array[i] += 1
        }
    }
}
```

and that compiled, but it seems as though the array was copied, in other words changing "array" did not affect "array1" or "array2".  I'd tried other variations of that using tuple.0 and tuple.1 notation, but could not get that to compile.  So then I tried using NSArrays instead of native Swift arrays ... but I couldn't figure out how to do that the right way, and in any case thought there must be a simpler way to do it.

Is there a succinct way of restating my original code so as not to duplicate the logic?

Comment: Sorry for the mix up with the migration earlier. The post has been reopened.

Comment: Should this not be on codereview as it's functional as is, and not overly inefficient?

Answer (score 4):

Curry it!

```
func func1(var a: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    a += [a[i-n]]
    return a
}

func func2(var a: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    a+= [Int (arc4random_uniform(7))]
    if a[i] >= a[i-n] {
        a[i] += 1
    }
    return a
}

func function(condition: Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int] {
    switch condition {
    case true:
        return func1
    case false:
        return func2
    }
 }

array1 = function(condition1)(array1)
array2 = function(condition2)(array2)
```

(and the same `inout` stuff that andyvn22 mentioned can apply here, too.)

Answer (score 1):

```
func alteredArray(var array:[Int], condition: Bool) -> [Int] {
    if condition {
        array += [array[i-n]]
    } else {
        array += [Int (arc4random_uniform(7))]
        if array[i] >= array[i-n] {
            array[i] += 1
        }
    }
    return array
}

array1 = alteredArray(array1, condition1)
array2 = alteredArray(array2, condition2)
```

Or, if you're feeling terse, rename the function, make `array` an `inout` parameter, remove the `return`, and call it as:

```
alterArray(&array1, condition1)
alterArray(&array2, condition1)
```